# How to modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf to make nginx work as a load balancer?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have two servers running the same web service, and I have another server running nginx, which redirects user requests to one of the two web servers.

```
              /------> web server1 (10.56.0.1)
user --> nginx
              \------> web server2 (10.56.0.2)
```

I can make it work by adding `upstream` and `proxy_pass` directly to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

```
http {
    ...
    upstream backend {
        server 10.56.0.1:80;
        server 10.56.0.2:80;
    }   
    server {
        ...
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's a good idea to directly change `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, I want put `upstream` and `proxy_pass` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, but it doesn't work, why? My complete configurations are as follows.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** (unmodified)

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
upstream backend {
        server 10.56.0.1:80;
        server 10.56.0.2:80;
}

server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should remove the default server in nginx.conf. That shouldn't be there

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention any **server_name** in the file "/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf", on the other hand you have 
`server_name  _;` 
block **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**, so all traffics are pointed in server block of **nginx.conf** file.

I would like to suggest to remove below line  from **nginx.conf** and put it in default.conf

```
server_name  _;
```

So your **default.conf**  will be

```
upstream backend {

    server 10.56.0.1:80;
    server 10.56.0.2:80;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    location / {

        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

For more look at https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I didn't make it work by playing around `server_name _;`, but I made it work by remove the entire `server` block in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint given by @solvease, I solved the problem by commenting the `server` block in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and adding the `server_name` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

Changes in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# server {
#         listen       80 default_server;
#         listen       [::]:80 default_server;
#         server_name  _;
#         root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
# 
#         # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#         include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
# 
#         location / {
#         }
# 
#         error_page 404 /404.html;
#             location = /40x.html {
#         }
# 
#         error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#             location = /50x.html {
#         }
#     }
```

Changes in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name _;
}
```

Comment: now alpine nginx docker image, does not have a server section, so in conf.d you can add it without problems